# How to create a column in a pandas dataframe based on a previous state?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithmic-trading

I have a pandas Dataframe with a timeseries index.
One column contains buy signals, another contains sell signals.

```
buy     0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sell    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

I want to add a state to this simplistic model: have a maximum of 1 stock at any time: Only buy when you currently have nothing, and sell when you have a stock.

```
buy     0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
sell    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0
wallet  0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How would I create the `df['wallet']` column based on `df['buy']` and `df['sell']`?

Comment: Can you give a better example? The relationship between buy and sell columns with wallet is not clear.

Comment: I guess wallet should be set to zero, when sell is one, and to one, when buy is one. But OPs should clearly state the algorithm in their question.

Comment: @MohitMotwani the wallet would be the state, and the maximum count in the wallet is 1.

When there is a buy signal and you have 0 in your wallet, actually place a buy order. When there is a buy signal and you already have something in your wallet, do nothing. For selling it's the same but reverse, only sell something when you have something in your wallet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

wallet = 0


def create_wallet(df_line):
    global wallet

    if df_line['buy']:
        wallet = 1

    elif df_line['sell']:
        wallet = 0

    return wallet


df = pd.DataFrame(
{'buy': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'sell': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
df['wallet'] = df.apply(create_wallet, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the prettiest solution, but I believe it achieves what you're looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'buy':  [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0], 
                    'sell': [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]   })


df['wallet'] = pd.np.where(df['buy'] - df['sell'] < 0, 0, df['buy'].cumsum().count() - df['sell'].cumsum())
df.loc[df['wallet'] > 1, 'wallet'] = 1
```

Comment: This fails if there are more sell than buy signals. If you leftpad your example with 3 zeroes for buy orders and 3 ones for sell orders, your wallet gets a lot of negative values

Comment: @Jasper - good call.  Just added a `.count()` that should do the trick

Comment: cumsum.count() just gives an arbitrarily high value which you later normalize to 1 anyway. If you use the .cumsum().count() approach on the leftpadded example, wallet is always the inverse of the sell column, which gives false positives for buy=0 & sell = 0